# Issue with Crashlytics logging when using Crashlytics in a dynamic framework

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I'm including Crashlytics in a dynamic framework which is used as a platform for multiple flavours of my app. I initialise it in the platform framework with an API Key fetched from the app target's Info.plist.

My Crashlytics logger, a wrapper around crashlytics logging, is in another framework which I import into my app.

The problem I'm having is that the Crashlytics logger complains that Crashlytics is not initialised even though it is:

`[Crashlytics:Crash] WARNING: CLSLog has been used before (or concurrently with) Crashlytics initialization and cannot be recorded. The message was:`

And Crashlytics does not upload the logs related to a crash.

This issue goes away if I include the Crashlytics logger class in the same framework that Crashlytics is initialised in.

Any idea why this log appears and why it is resolved when the logging is in the same framework that Crashlytics was initialised?

Comment: Faced with exact the same issue. According to my debugging, Crashlytics lib creates something like log file in bundle where you call [Fabric with:]. And when you call CLS_LOG from another bundle, this file is missed and lib thinks that app was not initialize Crashlytics.